# Splitting a url into a list in python

Tags: python, urlparse, urlsplit

I am currently working on a project that involves splitting a url. I have used the urlparse module to break up the url, so now I am working with just the path segment.

The problem is that when I try to split() the string based on the delimiter "/" to separate the directories, I end up with empty strings in my list.

For example, when I do the following:

```
import urlparse
url = "http://example/url/being/used/to/show/problem"
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
path = parsed[2] #this is the path element

pathlist = path.split("/")
```

I get the list:

```
['', 'url', 'being', 'used', 'to', 'show', 'problem']
```

I do not want these empty strings. I realize that I can remove them by making a new list without them, but that seems sloppy. Is there a better way to remove the empty strings and slashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with urllib and its output for path but think  that one way to form new list you can use list comprehension the following way:

```
[x for x in path.split("/") if x]
```

Or something like this if only leading '/':

```
path.lstrip('/').split("/")
```

Else if trailing too:

```
path.strip('/').split("/")
```

And at least if your string in path always starting from single '/' than the easiest way is:

```
path[1:].split('/')
```

Answer (score 5):

> I do not want these empty strings. I realize that I can remove them by making a new list without them, but that seems sloppy. Is there a better way to remove the empty strings and slashes?

What? There's only **one** empty string and it's always first, by definition.

```
pathlist = path.split("/")[1:]
```

Is pretty common.

---

A trailing slash can mean an "empty" filename.  In which case, a default name may be implied (index.html, for example)

It may be meaningful.

```
"http://example/url/being/used/to/show/problem"
```

The filename is "problem"

```
"http://example/url/being/used/to/show/problem/"
```

The directory is "problem" and a default filename is implied by the empty string.

Comment: If the url has a slash at the end, there is another empty string.

Comment: Then maybe use a list comp?
`path_list = [(p)  for p in path.split('/')  if len(p)]`

Comment: @craigs: It's not arbitrary.  It's the first position only.  The last position may be meaningful.  Simply suppressing path elements is wrong.

Comment: @S.Lott: I _completely_ agree with your original response and **do** understand the significance of trailing slashes for most web servers; but I was responding to @chindes later response that indicated for their particular situation they wanted to suppress _all_ empty strings in the split.  So…would the only safe way to decide whether or not to suppress the trailing '/' be to actually issue a HEAD request and check for a redirect? 
p.s. ['I almost wet myself'](http://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.com/2011/07/i-almost-wet-myself.html) when I got a response from S.Lott.

Comment: @craigs: "they wanted to suppress all empty strings in the split" is a Really Bad Idea.  It's an Attractive Nuisance.

Answer (score 2):

```
pathlist = paths.strip('/').split("/")
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the empty items?

```
pathlist.remove('')
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this as a comment to a comment, so just in case:
Couldn't you use a list comprehension to exclude the empty elements returned from the split, i.e.

```
path_list = [(p) for p in path.split('/') if len(p)]
```